# How do I display multiple model schemas on ngOnInit() Angular, Mongodb, Express

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, model-view-controller, mean-stack

I'm currently struggling trying to load two seperate model schemas onto my home-page.html using 'let cat of cats' and 'let dog of dogs'. When my home-page loads I want it to populate each table with the according animal's data, but instead it will only load the cats on both tables or the dogs if I switch up the `this.dogs = data` to `this.cats = data`

These are my models.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    breedname: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3 },
    age: { type: Number, required: true, minlength: 2 },
    gender: { type: String, required: true},
    comfortablecatdog: { type: String},
    comfortablekids: { type: String},
    health: { type: String, required: true},

}, { timestamps: true });

mongoose.model('Cat', CatSchema);

var DogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    breedname: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3 },
    age: { type: Number, required: true, minlength: 2 },
    gender: { type: String, required: true},
    comfortablecatdog: { type: String},
    comfortablekids: { type: String},
    health: { type: String, required: true},

}, { timestamps: true });

mongoose.model('Dog', DogSchema);
```

My controllers..

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat');
var Dog = mongoose.model('Dog');
module.exports = {
    index: function (req, res) {
        console.log('hit index controller');
        Cat.find({}, function (err, breedname) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('got an error at index');
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                console.log('rendered cats');
                res.json(breedname);
            }
        })
        Dog.find({}, function (err, breedname) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('got an error at index');
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                console.log('rendered dogs');
                res.json(breedname);
            }
        })

    },
```

My home-page html..

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 1px; padding: 15px;">
  <div class="table-responsive table-sm shadow-lg w-auto"
    style="border: 1px solid black; cursor: default; padding-right: 0; border-radius: 8px;">
    <table class="table table-hover w-auto" style="margin: 0; border-radius: 18px;">
      <thead>Cats
        <tr
          style="/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#fac695+0,f5ab66+47,ef8d31+100;Orange+3D+%232 */
        background: rgb(250,198,149); /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,198,149,1) 0%, rgba(245,171,102,1) 47%, rgba(239,141,49,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,198,149,1) 0%,rgba(245,171,102,1) 47%,rgba(239,141,49,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(250,198,149,1) 0%,rgba(245,171,102,1) 47%,rgba(239,141,49,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fac695', endColorstr='#ef8d31',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */; font-size: 25px; color: whitesmoke; font-size: 17px;">
          <th scope="col">Breed Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Age</th>
          <th scope="col">Gender</th>
          <th scope="col">Comfortable around other pets/animals?</th>
          <th scope="col">Comfortable around children/people?</th>
          <th scope="col">Any known health issues?</th>
          <th scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="font-size: 17.1px;">
        <tr *ngFor="let cat of cats">
          <td>{{cat.breedname}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.age}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.comfortablecatdog}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.comfortablekids}}</td>
          <td>{{cat.health}}</td>
          <button
            style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 164, 240, 0.267); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
            [routerLink]="['/cats', cat._id]">Details</button>
          <button
            style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 217, 0, 0.267); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
            [routerLink]="['/cats', cat._id, 'edit']">Edit</button>
          <!-- <button style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.226); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
            [routerLink]="['/cats', cat._id, 'delete']">Delete</button> -->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin: 1px; padding: 15px;">
  <div class="table-responsive table-sm shadow-lg w-auto"
    style="border: 1px solid black; cursor: default; padding-right: 0; border-radius: 8px;">
    <table class="table table-hover w-auto" style="margin: 0; border-radius: 18px;">
      <thead>Dogs
        <tr
          style="/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#fac695+0,f5ab66+47,ef8d31+100;Orange+3D+%232 */
        background: rgb(250,198,149); /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,198,149,1) 0%, rgba(245,171,102,1) 47%, rgba(239,141,49,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,198,149,1) 0%,rgba(245,171,102,1) 47%,rgba(239,141,49,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(250,198,149,1) 0%,rgba(245,171,102,1) 47%,rgba(239,141,49,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fac695', endColorstr='#ef8d31',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */; font-size: 25px; color: whitesmoke; font-size: 17px;">
          <th scope="col">Breed Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Age</th>
          <th scope="col">Gender</th>
          <th scope="col">Comfortable around other pets/animals?</th>
          <th scope="col">Comfortable around children/people?</th>
          <th scope="col">Any known health issues?</th>
          <th scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="font-size: 17.1px;">
        <tr *ngFor="let dog of dogs">
          <td>{{dog.breedname}}</td>
          <td>{{dog.age}}</td>
          <td>{{dog.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{dog.comfortablecatdog}}</td>
          <td>{{dog.comfortablekids}}</td>
          <td>{{dog.health}}</td>
          <button
            style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 164, 240, 0.267); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
            [routerLink]="['/dogs', dog._id]">Details</button>
          <button
            style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 217, 0, 0.267); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
            [routerLink]="['/dogs', dog._id, 'edit']">Edit</button>
          <!-- <button style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.226); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
            [routerLink]="['/dogs', dog._id, 'delete']">Delete</button> -->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my home-page.ts

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  newCat: any;
  newDog: any;
  cats = [];
  dogs = [];
  // cat = {breedname: ''};
  // dog = {breedname: ''};


  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _httpService: HttpService, private _router: Router, ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var tempObeservable = this._httpService.getAllPets();
    tempObeservable.subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('got a response from ngoninit', data);
      this.dogs = data;
      this.cats = data;
    });
  }
```

My http.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { identifierModuleUrl } from '@angular/compiler';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }
  getAllPets(){
    console.log('getAllPets');
    return this._http.get('/api/pets');
  }
  getCatById(_id){
    console.log('getCatById');
    let breedquestion = this._http.get(`/api/pets/${_id}/editcat`);
    return breedquestion;
  }
  getDogById(_id){
    console.log('getDogById');
    let breedquestion = this._http.get(`/api/pets/${_id}/editdog`);
    return breedquestion;
  }
  updateCatInfo(breedObj){
    console.log('UpdateCat')
    return this._http.post('/api/pets/'+breedObj._id+'/updatecat', breedObj);
  }
  updateDogInfo(breedObj){
    console.log('UpdateDog')
    return this._http.post('/api/pets/'+breedObj._id+'/updatedog', breedObj);
  }
  postNewCat(breedObj){
    console.log('postnewCat')
    return this._http.post('/api/pets/newcat', breedObj);
  }
  postNewDog(breedObj){
    console.log('postnewDog')
    return this._http.post('/api/pets/newdog', breedObj);
  }
```

my controllers with commented code

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat');
var Dog = mongoose.model('Dog');
module.exports = {
    index: function (req, res) {
        console.log('hit index controller');
        // When the page loads, I want my Cats and Dogs to load into each of their tables

        Cat.find({}, function (err, breedname) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('got an error at index');
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                console.log('rendered cats');
                res.json(breedname);
            }
        })
        Dog.find({}, function (err, breedname) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('got an error at index');
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                console.log('rendered dogs');
                res.json(breedname);
            }
        // -----------------------------------------

        })
    },
```

I already kind of know that my ngOnInit() is taking two 'data' parameters when it should only be one, I have just left it this way because I'm not sure what to do. A bit of a newbie here.

Any suggestions? Apologies if this has already been answered.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the `_httpService` code and also i noticed that you are directly assigning the data to both `dogs` and `cats` which will create duplicate entries.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stack, Why won't it let me reply to you with more code?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the _httpService

Comment: @JijoCleetus just did. I included my pets.js controller once more with more info of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly fix your controller to give both cats and dogs in some way like this

```
Promise.all([
  Cat.find({}).exec(),
  Dog.find({}).exec()
])
.then(([cats, dogs]) => res.json({cats, dogs}))
.catch((err) => res.status(500).json(err))
```

and  then fix subscription to handle this

```
 tempObeservable.subscribe(({cats, dogs}) => {
      console.log('got a response from ngoninit', cats, dogs);
      this.dogs = dogs;
      this.cats = cats;
    });
```

the problem is you are trying to response 2 times on a single request in your backend code, and that is not possible. I did respond 1 time with {cats, dogs} json object

Comment: After adding those to my homepagecomponent.ts and pets.js controller I'm getting the error 'Property Cat does not exist on type Object' in my homepagecomponent.ts

Comment: that is typescript compile time error. to fix that you should add proper type to getAllPets get request. It is better to do here 
`getAllPets() {
 return return this._http.get<{cats: any[], dogs: any[]}>('/api/pets');
}`

Comment: That seems to have fixed it but now I'm getting 'cannot find name data' from the console.log     `var tempObeservable = this._httpService.getAllPets();
    tempObeservable.subscribe(({ cats, dogs }) => {
      console.log('got a response from ngoninit', data);
      this.dogs = dogs;
      this.cats = cats;
    });
  } `

Comment: you are right, i forgot to also fix console.log, as no data variable is available after my changes. I fixed in answer btw

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Apologies, I thought upvoting it would and I dont have enough reputation yet lol. Fixed it.